# Simplifying g++ command on Windows

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, linkage, msys2

I have been toying around with javidx9's [olcPixelGameEngine](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine) (a single-header game prototyping engine) for a while now, but I have been experiencing some problems related to the necessary libraries for compiling the code. The header file offers many `#pragma comment` for telling Visual Studio what libraries to link, but since I can't use Visual Studio (my computer is very old and can't run it well), I tried compiling by hand, linking each library. The resulting command ended up being something like `g++ .\main.cpp -std=c++17 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lgdiplus -lShlwapi -lstdc++fs`, which is a tad too big for my liking. Is there a way to simplify this entire command into something reusable for other `.cpp` files? I thought of `make` files, but since I use mostly Windows, I don't know how to use them. Being able to link automatically, or just mixing all those flags into a single command would be very helpful.

I'm currently using MinGW, installed with MSYS2, for compiling, if that can help.

Comment: Why not use a build system like `cmake`, `scons`, `make`, `ninja` or *many* others, so you can specify how to build your code once and for all and not have to manually type in long command lines all the time? Then the length of the command line becomes irrelevant.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: @ThomasSablik sorry about that. I rephrased the question now. English is not my native language, so I tend to write questions in a bit of a round-about way.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I thought that buildsystems like `cmake` and `scons` were for much larger projects, so I wanted to avoid them for now. But I will take a look into it.

Comment: @Carmo They are useful for projects of *any* size. Literally the *first* thing I do when starting a project (after `git init` of course) is write a bare bones `CMakeLists.txt` file. Even before adding the first source file to the repository.

Comment: I'm still a beginner when it comes to buildsystems, so for simple cases like mine (as I described in the question above), would it be better to jump straight into CMake or should I pick up Make For Windows first? @JesperJuhl

Comment: @Carmo I'd go for `cmake`. It's a "meta build system" that can generate build files for Visual Studio, make, Ninja and many others. And if you keep to the basics and keep it simple it's fairly easy to get started with. And it has kind of won the "mindshare" battle, so there's lots of help to find online (although its syntax kinda sucks).

Comment: Alright, I will get started with that, then. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You can make a bash script or Windows batch script that runs that command so you don't have to remember it.